# How to compare alphanumeric values in Perl?

Tags: string, perl, comparison, alphanumeric

Here is my code-

```
print $cpu_arch."\n";  
if ($cpu_arch eq'AMD64') {      
    print "Remote machine is 64bit\n";
}
```

Depending upon the CPU architecture, $cpu_arch returns x86 or AMD64. 
The problem is that no matter what $cpu_arch returns, the if loop condition is not getting satisfied. I've tried chomp'ing the $cpu_arch but that doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Have you tried double quotes, like "AMD64"? Also, are you sure you're not getting extra whitespace? Regex comparison may be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator for string is `eq` as you have. Your issue isn't in your operator it is in the data. More than likely you are buffering improperly ( change the `$|` variable ) or your `$cpu_arch` has trailing white-space. Or maybe you are looking for regex match and not literal match ( then you want `/AMD64/` )

Comment: Thanks! Regex works just fine. Probably something wrong with buffering as you mentioned.

Comment: The regex working suggests that it's not a buffering issue but rather a trailing whitespace issue.

Comment: What the heck are you talking about when you say "buffering improperly"?

Comment: That is probably bad phrasing. What I mean is that STDOUT isn't flushing so it looks like nothing is printing when in fact it is, but your terminal isn't displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. Either `$cpu_arch` doesn't contain `AMD64`, or you are mistaken about the `if` condition being false (perhaps because of buffering).

The following might help you examine `$cpu_arch`.

```
use Data::Dumper;

{
   local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
   print(Dumper($cpu_arch));
}
```